# Forcing Celery to use Python 3

Tags: python, celery

I'm sorry if this is a silly question but this is my first day using Celery and I am having a difficult time getting it to use python3. I've included this shebang in all of my files...

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

The stack trace is reporting errors raise by python2.7...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
```

The app was run with this command...

```
celery -A GidConsumer worker --loglevel=info
```

Comment: how do you run the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in a Python project, you'll install all dependencies (including celery) into a virtualenv. Then, when you want to run `celery`, you'll activate your virtual environment and it will find the `celery` executable in your PATH. There's a lot of detail not included here, but in general, it's a bad idea to try to globally install stuff and it leads to lots of hassles.

The alternative in this case is to find the celery package that you globally installed under Python3 (did you use `pip3` to install it?). Figure out which `bin` that celery landed in and you can use its full path to call it by including its full path in that `bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Please uninstall celery with pip(pip uninstall celery) and reinstall celery with PIP 3(pip3 install celery).... :)